# converting String that contains Letters to Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i got a string that looks like :

```
2012-10-01 13:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

i want to change it to DateTime format in python, I've tried this

```
data['dt']=pd.to_datetime(data['dt'])
```

and got the following errors:

```
1- TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

2- ValueError: Unknown string format
```

also tried to add  `format='%d%b%Y %H:%M'` but got errors number 1 and

```
ValueError: time data '2012-10-01 12:00:00 +0000 UTC' does not match format '%d%b%Y %H:%M' (match)
```

Comment: Are all date times in UTC time?

Comment: If yes, you can use: `data['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dt'].str.rsplit(None, 1).str[0]).dt.tz_localize('utc'))`

Comment: So make the format match... What is tripping you up exactly? See `%Z` in https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data['dt']=pd.to_datetime(data['dt'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +%f %Z')
```

Comment: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +%f %Z'` would be better.

Comment: @MaxU Thanks, my eyes skimmed over the `f` and went straight to the hardcoded UTC!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this:

```
import time
pd.to_datetime(time.strptime('2012-10-01 13:00:00 +0000 UTC', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z'))
```

Comment: You shouldn't recommend this, it doesn't work with string columns.

Comment: This might work well with scalar value, but it will be painfully slow if we try to apply it to a long vector (DF's column)...